# About the use of "request"

Tags: verbs

Which one is correct?

> 1. I requested the police to permit me to enter the house.
> 2. I requested permitting me to enter the house from the police.
> 3. I requested to permit me to enter the house.
> 4. I requested it from the police permitting me to enter the house from the police.
> 5. I requested it from the police to permit me to enter the house.

I think 1,3,5 are correct, but only 2 and 4 barely make sense.
I want to know the reason why if there's something wrong.
Personally, I guess such a sentence structure like 2 as "request gerund from object" should be avoidable as people can misunderstand "from" as modifying "gerund" in meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of these, only #1 is fully correct.

"I requested" should usually be followed by **who** you are making the request of, or by **what** you are requesting. Often both are specified.

> - I requested John to help Jane (who= John, what=to help Jane)
> - I requested access to the computer. (what=access to the computer)

When a "what" is specified, it should usually be a noun or noun phrase

In #2

> I requested permitting me to enter the house from the police.

"permitting me" is not a noun phrase nor does it function as one.

In #3

> I requested to permit me to enter the house

there needs to be a {who} before the "to"

> I requested Jack to permit me to enter the house

In #4

> I requested it from the police permitting me to enter the house from the police.

"permitting" does not work in this context. One might say

> - I requested permission from the police for me to enter the house.
> - I needed permission to enter the house. I requested it from the police.